# Error in my logcat, after some refreshes on my list my app crashes

Tags: java, android

## Posts.java

```
public class Posts extends Activity implements OnCheckedChangeListener {

private static final String TAG = "POSTS";
private static final int NULL_COUNTRY_CODE = 6;
private static final int POST_BACK_BTN = 7;
private static final int CHANGE = 8;

private String un;
private SimpleAdapter simpleAdpt;
private EditText post;
private RadioGroup radGrp;
private GPSTracker mGPS;
private PullToRefreshListView lv;
private String initial = "Se eida ";
private String code;
private String unm;
private String postui;
private String tmp;
private String idPost;

// The data to show
private List<Map<String, String>> postsList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

JSONArray array = null;

private static List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

private String pst;

private AlertDialogFragments adf;
private FragmentTransaction ft;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_posts);

    initLocation();

    if (code == null) {

        ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        // Create and show the dialog.
        adf = new AlertDialogFragments(NULL_COUNTRY_CODE);
        adf.show(ft, "dialog");
    }

    init();

}

private HashMap<String, String> createPost(String key, String name) {

    HashMap<String, String> post = new HashMap<String, String>();

    post.put(key, name);

    return post;

}

private void initLocation() {

    mGPS = new GPSTracker(this);

    final double mLat = mGPS.getLatitude();
    final double mLong = mGPS.getLongitude();

    getAddress(mLat, mLong);

}

private void getAddress(double mLat, double mLong) {

    try {
        Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
        List<Address> addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(mLat, mLong, 100);
        if (addresses.size() > 0) {

        
            addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(mLat, mLong, 1);
            code = addresses.get(0).getCountryCode();

            
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void init() {

    this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

    Intent i = getIntent();

    un = i.getStringExtra("un");

    post = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lbl_txt);

    radGrp = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rdg);
    radGrp.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

    // We get the ListView component from the layout

    lv = (PullToRefreshListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    // Set a listener to be invoked when the list should be refreshed.
    ((PullToRefreshListView) lv)
            .setOnRefreshListener(new OnRefreshListener() {
                @Override
                public void onRefresh() {
                    ((PullToRefreshListView) lv)
                            .setLastUpdated(new SimpleDateFormat(
                                    "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm").format(new Date()));
                    new GetData().execute();
                }
            });


    simpleAdpt = new CustomAdapter(this, postsList,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new String[] { "post" },
            new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });

    new GetData().execute();

}

public class CustomAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public CustomAdapter(Context context,
            List<? extends Map<String, String>> data, int resource,
            String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, data, resource, from, to);

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        if (row != null) {
            if (position % 2 == 0)
                row.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.listview_selector_even);
            else
                row.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.listview_selector_odd);
        }

        return row;
    }

}


private class GetData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    private ProgressDialog progDailog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        progDailog = new ProgressDialog(Posts.this);
        progDailog.setMessage("Loading...");
        progDailog.setIndeterminate(false);
        progDailog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        progDailog.setCancelable(true);
        progDailog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        postsList.clear();
        list.clear();

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                //getting data from server and store into results

                try {
                    array = new JSONArray(result);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject row = null;
                    try {
                        row = array.getJSONObject(i);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    try {
                        unm = row.getString("Username");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    try {
                        postui = row.getString("Post");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    try {
                        tmp = row.getString("Timestamp");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    try {
                        idPost = row.getString("Id");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    pst = unm + ":\n" + postui + "\n"
                            + tmp.substring(0, tmp.length() - 2);

                    list.add(i, idPost);

                    postsList.add(createPost("post", pst));

                }

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        lv.setSelector(R.drawable.row_pressed);
                        lv.setAdapter(simpleAdpt);
                        simpleAdpt.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        registerForContextMenu(lv);

                    }

                });

            }
        }).start();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {
        super.onPostExecute(unused);
        simpleAdpt.notifyDataSetChanged();
        progDailog.dismiss();
        ((PullToRefreshListView) lv).onRefreshComplete();
    }
}

// We want to create a context Menu when the user long click on an item
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    AdapterContextMenuInfo aInfo = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;

    // We know that each row in the adapter is a Map
    HashMap<?, ?> map = (HashMap<?, ?>) simpleAdpt
            .getItem(aInfo.position - 1);

    String string = (String) map.get("post");

    menu.setHeaderTitle("Options");
    
        menu.add(1, 1, 1, "Share via:");
        menu.add(1, 2, 2, "Copy");
        menu.add(1, 3, 3, "Delete");

        menu.add(1, 1, 1, "Share via:");
        menu.add(1, 2, 2, "Copy");
    

}

// This method is called when user selects an Item in the Context menu
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int itemId = item.getItemId();

    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item
            .getMenuInfo();

    switch (itemId) {
    case 1:
        // Share intent

        String key = ((TextView) info.targetView).getText().toString();

        // create the send intent
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

        // set the type
        shareIntent.setType("text/plain");

        // add a subject
        shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
                R.string.app_name);

        // build the body of the message to be shared
        String shareMessage = key.substring(0, key.length() - 20)
                .substring(key.indexOf(":") + 2);

        // add the message
        shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                shareMessage);

        // start the chooser for sharing
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share via: "));

        break;
    case 2:
        // Copy

        String key1 = ((TextView) info.targetView).getText().toString();

        int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

        if (sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            android.text.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.text.ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
            clipboard.setText(key1.substring(0, key1.length() - 20)
                    .substring(key1.indexOf(":") + 2));

            Toast.makeText(this, "Post copied.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else {
            android.content.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.content.ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
            android.content.ClipData clip = android.content.ClipData
                    .newPlainText("", key1.substring(0, key1.length() - 20)
                            .substring(key1.indexOf(":") + 2));
            clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);

            Toast.makeText(this, "Post copied.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        break;
    case 3:
        // Delete

        int index = info.position - 1;

                    //deletes a post
        deletePost(list.get(index), this);

        new GetData().execute();

        break;

    }

    return true;
}
```

## My Logcat output

> The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a
> notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified
> from a background thread, but only from the UI thread.

Comment: Why do you start a new Thread inside doInBackground? The beauty of the AsyncTask class is that you don't have to do that. doInBackground always runs in its own thread.

Comment: Logcat typically will specify exactly where your errors are occurring in terms of class name and line number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using postList as content for your adapter. Then you change that content in doInBackground(). You cannot do that.

Here's what you have to do. Gather the data in doInBackground() and return it. The result will be passed to onPostExecute. Then, in onPostExecute, change the adapter content and notify about the data change. onPostExecute() runs in the UI thread.

If you want to periodically update your AdapterView, use publishProgress.

You don't need to start a new Thread in doInBackground and you don't need to invoke any runOnUIThread method. It will work (especially the runOnUIThread part) but then you don't need the AsyncTask class.